# debug2: channel <x>: window <number> sent adjust <number_2>

Tags: ssh, tmux

I'm modifying a file in `vim` inside of a `tmux` session and this line (that is not part of the file) keeps popping up on my cursor line:

`debug2: channel 0: window  99720 sent adjust 6670`

Why is this message popping up and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This message is the result of connecting to a machine using `ssh` with the `-vv` flag turned on. In my case I'd used `-vv` to diagnose why a client machine was rejecting my connection and had forgotten to close and reopen the session without debug flags after diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Thanks. You should mark this as an answer.